# Can't dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and WIndows 10

Tags: dual-boot

While installing Ubuntu I can't see free space that I have partitioned from HDD so can't dual boot. Please help me out

Comment: Most common reason: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions But if SSD, you may need firmware updates. And should make sure UEFI is newest version whether dual booting or not. Also some systems have RAID or Intel SRT for drive settings in UEFI, which needs to be AHCI. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI